# Переход по ссылке только после второго клика

Tags: javascript, jquery, link, click

Нужно запретить переход по ссылке при первом клике и разрешить только после второго. Написал код:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").attr("data-count", "0");
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").on("click", function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        clickCount ++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            $(this).attr("dataCount", clickCount);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Не работает, в чём может быть ошибка?
Второй вариант тоже не работает

```
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").attr("data-count", "0");
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").on("click", function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
        clickCount ++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            $(this).attr("dataCount", clickCount);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант:

```
 $(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").attr("data-count", "0");
    $(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").on("click", function() {
        var clickCount = $(this).attr("data-count");
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            $(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox[data-count='1']").attr("data-count", "0");
            $(this).attr("data-count", clickCount);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

И самый короткий, спасибо Ивану Беленкову.

```
$(".categoriesPage .categoryBox .textBox").one("click", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том что для подсчета кликов собирались использовать аттрибут `data-count`, а по факту используется глобальная переменная - одна на всю страницу.

И в коде еще откуда-то берется аттрибут `dataCount` - в который тоже только пишется значение, но никто его не читает.